# Can Boolean value produce number values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have found a solution for one of quiz I have in working with JavaScript data structure, in which an object (named game) was given as following.

```
const game = {
  score: '4:0',
  scored: ['Lewandowski', 'Gnarby', 'Lewandowski', 'Hummels'], //Names of players
  date: 'Nov 9th, 2037',
  odds: {
    team1: 1.33,
    x: 3.25,
    team2: 6.5,
  },
};
```

Quiz or challenge is: Create an object called 'scorers' which contains the names of the players who scored as properties, and the number of goals as the value. In this game, it will look like this:

```
{
  Gnarby: 1,
  Hummels: 1,
  Lewandowski: 2
}
```

I found the following solution:

```
let scorers = {};
let arr = Object.values(game.scored);
for(const player of arr) {
   scorers[player] = (scorers[player] || 0) + 1;
}
console.log(scorers);

// {Lewandowski: 2, Gnarby: 1, Hummels: 1}
```

My question is how the syntax `scorers[player] = (scorers[player] || 0) + 1;` produces values for each player property though it will be true or false, and how at the end 1 will be added though it is of type number? How to interpret this code in simple language?

Comment: No, it won't produce a `boolean`. `scorers[player] || 0` will return the value of `scorers[player]` if it is already contained in the `scorers` object, or `0` otherwise. Then you add `1` to it and reassign it to `scorers[player]`. Thus, it will always be a number and never a boolean

Comment: Btw. as `game.scored` is an array, you can iterate it directly like `for (let player of game.scored)` and don't need `Object.values()`

Comment: ```const scorers = {};
for (let player of game.scored){
    scorers[player] = (scorers[player] || 0) + 1;
}
console.log(scorers)```  value would be 0 or added value will be considered in each iteration and assign as a new value for object property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike some other languages, JavaScript allows other data types to be used for what looks like purely boolean operators. In that case JavaScript will temporarily interpret a non-boolean as being "falsy" or "truthy".

There are two cases:

- `scorers[player]` is undefined. In that case the `||` operand will identify that value as a "falsy" value and will thus continue to evaluate the right operand, which is 0. So `(undefined || 0)` evaluates to 0.
- `scorers[player]` is defined, and (for this program) it will be a positive number. In that case the `||` operand will consider it "truthy" and not evaluate the right operand. So `(1 || 0)` evaluates to 1.

NB: In modern JavaScript it is now better practice to use the [`??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) operator for this use case instead of `||`.

Comment: Using ```scorers[player] = (scorers[player] ?? 0) + 1;``` would be same as using ```scorers[player] = (scorers[player] || 0) + 1;``` as property would have to be set as 0 when it is defined.

Comment: @VishalShukla, yes, in this case it would, but it is better practice, because `||` will behave differently when `scorers[player]` is defined, but is for instance the empty string. I know that this never happens in this particular case, but it is better practice to use an operator that specifically reacts to `undefined` and `null` and not to all "falsy" values. Indeed, in this particular case it would also work for falsy values, but in a more general case it could be different. (I didn't say it didn't work ;-) )

Comment: Anyway, did this answer your question?

Comment: Yes. Thank you.

Comment: It is explained in the link in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `scorers[player] || 0` is called [short circuit](https://codeburst.io/javascript-short-circuit-conditionals-bbc13ac3e9eb) in JavaScript.

It is as simple as `AND, OR AND NOT`  in Logical algebra. By default, a non-existing property in JS Object yields undefined( which means Boolean false ).
Here are some uses of the short circuit in JS.

[image]

Your statement `scorers[player] = (scorers[player] || 0` will result the socres[player] result if it exists or 0. When you did add 1 to it at, it will increment the current player goal count. That will result in 0 or +1 to the current score of the player. Each step involved in that statement is shown below.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, we [can't accept images of code, data or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Post those as *text*, so that others can try to reproduce tithe output without having to re-type everything, and your answer can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.